# Ability increase for extra HD not calculated correctly under the Lycanthrope entry in the Monster Manual?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, ability-scores, statistics

In the SRD it states:

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#abilityScoreImprovement

> Ability Score Improvement

> Treat monster Hit Dice the same as character level for determining ability score increases. This only applies to Hit Dice increases, monsters do not gain ability score increases for levels they "already reached" with their racial Hit Dice, since these adjustments are included in their basic ability scores.

Meaning that for every 4 hit dice a monster has it gains an ability score improvement of +1 on any one ability score. In the SRD in the monster entry for Lycanthrope under abilities section of the Creating a lycanthrope subsection is stated this:

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm

> All lycanthropes gain +2 to Wisdom. In addition, when in animal form, a lycanthrope’s physical ability scores improve according to its kind, as set out in the table below. These adjustments are equal to the animal’s normal ability scores -10 or -11. A lycanthrope in hybrid form modifies its physical ability scores by the same amount.
> **In addition, a lycanthrope may also gain an additional ability score increase by virtue of its extra Hit Dice.**

A werebear in human form has the following stats:

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm

> Str 13, Dex 11, Con 12, Int 10, Wis 11, Cha 8

And is based upon:

> The werebear presented here is a 1st-level human warrior and natural lycanthrope, using the following base ability scores: Str 13, Dex 11, Con 12, Int 10, Wis 9, Cha 8.

Otherwise known as the 'non elite array' or 'low powered campaign / 15 point buy'

The +2 increase to wisdom is the Wisdom bonus that a lycanthrope receives. Where is the +1 ability score increase to a stat from having 4 or more HD? As the statement '...*monsters do not gain ability score increases for levels they "already reached" with their racial Hit Dice, since these adjustments are included in their basic ability scores.*' seems to be incorrect because the adjustment has not been included.

Is this a mistake or something I am missing? Incidentally I have checked Cooper’s Compendium Of Corrected Creatures and no mention of this seeming discrepancy may be found in that source which makes me question whether it's something I've forgotten?

Further research of this problem indicates it isn't just constrained to lycanthropes take the Hound Archon Hero for example:

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/archon.htm#houndArchon

Page 6 & 7 of the Monster Manual inform that:

> Advanced creatures such as the hound archon hero are built using the elite array: 15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8.

The ability scores of the hound archon hero are:
Str 21, Dex 10, Con 16, Int 8, Wis 14, Cha 16

If the racial ability score modifiers (+4 Strength, +2 Constitution, +2 Wisdom, +2 Charisma) are deducted leaves: Str 17, Dex 10, Con 14, Int 8, Wis 12, Cha 14.

How were these scores arrived at from the elite array 15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8? The only possible way this was done was if the total ability score increase from class and HD was +3.

Str 15, Dex 10, Con 13, Int 8, Wis 12, Cha 14 with ability score increases of +2 Str and +1 Con.

This has been calculated by taking 6 Racial HD adjusting an ability score by +1 for the increase at 4 Racial HD and then taking 11 class levels of paladin adjusting ability scores by +2 for the class ability score adjustments at 4 and 8 class levels.

Because there is no other way of arriving at those totals this demonstrates that both racial hit dice and class levels comprise the calculation to adjust ability scores. However this then would still be incorrect because a 17 HD creature (6 Racial HD + 11 paladin class levels) should receive a +4 total ability score adjustment.

I believe the error is in that Racial HD and Paladin levels were calculated independent of one another for ability score adjustments.

Comment: I haven’t investigated these particular creatures, but it may be worth knowing that D&D 3.5e statblocks are *notorious* for errors like this. It would not be the least bit surprising if such a mistake had been made.

Comment: @KRyan I'm not certain of this statement 'monsters do not gain ability score increases for levels they "already reached" with their racial Hit Dice, since these adjustments are included in their basic ability scores' hence my reason for demonstrating the case of the Hound Archon Hero who it appears has gained adjustments from both racial HD and class levels.

Comment: Oh yeah, creature stat blocks are *supposed to* include those bonuses; I’m just saying it wouldn’t be terribly surprising if some did so incorrectly, or failed to do so altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The passage you have quoted comes into play, when you manage lycantrope's advancement. if it is only the base creature and the base animal, their stats already include advancement for those types of creatures.

For a human werebear it is one increase a bear has included in it's six racial Hit Dice.

For a lizardfolk werewolf, their four Hit Dice come with no ability score increases, but count against the total of Hit Dice to calculate the number of Hit Dice which actually provide increases.

So, for you to see resulting lycantrope's ability scores different from the sum of base creatures' scores, you will need something like werewolf lord - advanced version of werewolf basically.

He gains two ability score increases for his "additional" ten class levels (class levels deffinitely are Hit Dice), which both come to Strength in the case of werewolf lord.

Be it a lizardfolk warrior 6 werewolf, she would have only one increase - for her fourth "additional" Hit Dice of six.

Comment: A werebear is a 6HD creature Str 13, Dex 11, Con 12, Int 10, Wis 11, Cha 8 this is the same creature as a 1st level human warrior Str 13, Dex 11, Con 12, Int 10, Wis 9, Cha 8. A werebear gains +2 racial bonus to Wisdom, where are you seeing an ability increase? Other than the racial bonus nothing was adjusted.

Comment: @MichaelDorf The bear part has already gotten an ability score increase, so having the human get one, too, would be double-dipping? (I think that may be this answer's crux, but I think that its point could be clearer.)

Comment: @MichaelDorf HeyICanChan is correct. Your human form wouldn't see this increase, that is true. But to add it to your human form stats, it would be necessary to subtract it from "bonus stats" bear and hybrid forms are giving first. As far as I can tell, the game doesn't do it.

Comment: @annoyingimp I don't understand what you're saying. All I'm asking is where's the ability score increase for reaching 4HD which any 4HD creature would receive? We have the lycanthrope abilities based on a 1st level human warrior and as a 6HD creature, comparing the two shows no ability increase at 4HD.

Comment: @MichaelDorf The claim is that since the HD come from the bear, and the bear already had its increase from 4th level (it’s baked into the bear’s stats), you don’t get it again. Which seems plausible, ish, either as what they meant or as what the person doing the stat block accidentally did, but agreed it should be clearer.

Comment: @KRyan The stats are based on a 1st level human warrior using non elite array, it doesn't have anything to do with a bear. The only increase has been the lycanthrope's +2 racial bonus to Wisdom.

Comment: @MichaelDorf Yes, the claim in this answer is that *you do not get* that benefit in human form—that the HD you gained as a result of the lycanthrope template already came with the 4th-level ability bump, so you don’t get another one. You only see the benefit of that bump in bear form, when you use the bear’s stats. Which is a lot to read between the lines, but seems just barely plausible to me.

Comment: @MichaelDorf after checking more creatures with the template, I see my example is incorrect (while the main point stands). I'll edit in few days, making calculations for both human and lizardfolk for completeness.

Comment: @KRyan Gotcha, that breaks the attribute adjustment rule by rights it should apply across the board. But still it seems like a reasonable justification.

Comment: @MichaelDorf done. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @annoyingimp The calculation for the werewolf lord in human form is that he's actually gaining a +4 ability increase for all 16 HD (Fighter levels + Werewolf Lord hit dice) His creation attributes were using the elite array Str 15, Dex 13, Con 14, Int 10, Wis 8, Cha 12 increasing Str, Dex and twice on Wisdom each at the respective levels. Then he gets his +2 racial bonus to Wisdom but he's also wearing gauntlets of ogre power providing a +2 enhancement bonus to Strength.

Comment: @annoyingimp Everything then works out accurately when we use the subtract 10 or 11 rule on Dire Wolf and apply the results to both his Hybrid and Animal Forms.

Comment: @MichaelDorf Gauntlets have slipped past me. With them in mind I may say one thing - something in lycantropes' stat blocks is wrong :) I believe, overall, it should work the way I describe, and I thought "base ability scores" are those before icreases gained from levels. I don't even think wolves may wear gauntlets. Still, your math is a solid counter argument.

Comment: @annoyingimp 'I don't even think wolves may wear gauntlets' the thought did cross my mind so I compared the cloak of resistance across all three stat blocks and found it was included only on the human form so whoever wrote the stat block was at least conscious of what was or wasn't included. Now whether a wolf should be able to wear gauntlets is another question entirely, it's somewhere noted what quadrupeds may make use of but it monetarily slips my mind as to where.

Comment: @MichaelDorf this is strange to a degree, because wolf would teiretically have no sereous problems wearing shoulders slot item. Hybrid definitely wouldn't have any. Maybe, gauntlets are excluded from all forms' stat blocks? To check it, we need some other example humanoid taken through advancement process to try to know what "base ability scores" are.